# Reversed distributive property of two operations

Tags: abstract-algebra

Are there any examples of a "reversed" distributive property, i.e. $a*(b \circ c ) = (a \circ b) * (a \circ c)$, $* \neq \circ$?

Answer (score 1):

For a given vector space $V$ you can define two different bilinear products $a\ast b$ and $a\circ b$ on $V$ and require the identity $a\ast(b\circ c)=(a\circ b)\ast (a\circ c)$ for all $a,b,c\in V$. Of course, there are examples for such bi-algebra structures already in low dimensions (other examples are Poisson algebras having two products connected by a derivation rule. Furthermore, post-Lie algebras have also two different Lie bracktets and one bilinear product interacting by certain identities).

Answer (score 0):

For example, $* = \circ = \max$.

Comment: Well, okay, for $* \neq \circ$...